# Разделитель для Decimal в ASP.NET Core Web Api

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

В методе Post контроллер получает число с плавающей точкой. Если в качестве разделителя приходит запятая, то он ее игнорирует и, например, `22,22` превращается в `2222`. Точку же обрабатывает корректно.
Запрос формируется клиентом в формате json. Из него значение парсится как `decimal`
Подскажите как сделать чтобы корректный формат был только с запятой, а точка воспринималась как невалидная?

Comment: Получает именно _число_ (decimal) или _строку_ (string) в виде числа? Как именно получает: json, xml, какой-то другой формат? Или вообще двоичный?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, JSON. В нем числа с плавающей точкой передаются в двойных кавычках, т.е. строкой. Но модель в контроллере использует decimal

Comment: Введенные в форму значения парсятся в _числа_ (decimal) или остаются _строками_ (string)? Контроллер ожидает данные в формате json. Как этот json формируется клиентом? Добавьте информацию в вопрос.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov добавил

Answer (score 0):

Решил таким способом

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.Culture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL"));
```

Осталось разобраться с поведением относительно точки

Comment: У вас на самом деле используется голландская (Нидерланды) культура?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да

Comment: Я имею в виду, что и пользователи посылают данные на ваш сервер в этой культуре?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, это не отслеживается. Просто есть договоренность, что в форме вводятся числа с запятой в качестве разделителя

Comment: Так почему голландская культура-то? Вы же, наверное, на русский язык рассчитываете? Тогда почему не `"ru-RU"`?